# ошибка kivy не работает с другими модулями

Tags: python, kivy, ursina

киви не работает с модулем ursina и выдает:

> TypeError: minecraft() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

код:

```
from ursina import *#модули
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import 
FirstPersonController
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from time import sleep
def minecraft1():#майнкрафт
    app = Ursina()

    class Voxel(Button):
        def __init__(self, position=(0, 0, 0)):
            super().__init__(
                parent=scene,
                position=position,
                model='cube',
                origin_y=.5,
                texture='white_cube',
                color=color.color(0, 0, random.uniform(.9, 1.0)),
                highlight_color=color.red,
            )

        def input(self, key):
            if self.hovered:
                if key == 'left mouse down':
                    voxel = Voxel(position=self.position + mouse.normal)

                if key == 'right mouse down':
                    destroy(self)

    for z in range(15):
        for x in range(15):
            voxel = Voxel(position=(x, 0, z))
            voxel = Voxel(position=(x, -1, z))
            voxel = Voxel(position=(x, -2, z))
            voxel = Voxel(position=(x, -20, z))
            voxel = Voxel(position=(x, -50, z))
    player = FirstPersonController()
def minecraft(self,instance):#запуск майна
    minecraft1()
    ursina().run()
class mia(App): #создание киви
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="моя кнопка",on_press=minecraft)
mia().run() #запуск киви
```

Comment: Как вы собираетесь соединить эти две библиотеки?

Comment: Ну так почему вы не передаёте аргумент instance?

Comment: александр если вы имеете ввиду добавить в функцию minecraft instance то это уже там написано а если внести аргумент туда то я не доконца в этом разбираюсь и не знаю что и как туда передовать

Comment: Может просто убрать его надо оттуда?

Comment: Для чего вам ursina нужна?

Comment: user:236044 мне охото майнкрафт добавить на своего голосого асисестента а так ладно если не смогу найти ответ обайдусь pygame

Comment: Вам вообще стоит Python поучить ещё, так как вы куролесите в скрипте.

Comment: хорошо извените я peep8 и много еще не знаю в коде

Comment: Вы хотите запускать майкравт или управлять героем, из сторонней программы?